# Can I tap the hot wire leading to stove hood vent fan to power a low current LED warning bulb by mean of induction?

Tags: power, led, induction, overheat

I cannot hear the hood vent fan running and I waste a lot of electricity. I know about lighted fan switches but they are not always found in every stove hood. Mine has no lighted fan switch. I use the hood vent fan a lot to take the fumes out of the gas burners.
I wonder if I can wind a thin gauge wire around the hot wire that is already separate from the ground wire and drill a hole for the LED light bulb assbly. Then the LED bulb will feed off the induced power independently.
I had searched for similar lighted fan switches but none of them match my type of fan switch as it is a hi/low switch and I don't want to mess with the nice placement of the switch on the front of the hood. I just thought about a possible LED bulb that is powered by the induction.
I studied electronics a little but I need a lazy answer here and quick.
If it is possible then how many winds do I need  that is enough to power a round LED bulb.
I am sure that many of us forget to turn off hood vent fans because we cannot hear them .. many of us are hard of hearing and so forth. I know that hood vent fans consumes considerate amount of power usually around 50 W.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to create a mechanical indicator which will move with airflow. Various options exist such as a short length of plastic ribbon hanging from the hood, a small plastic beach "windmill" or a flap which when moved would reveal a fluorescent "flag" of some type.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have not told us your AC Mains voltage.

Probably not using induction but possibly can be done using capacitive coupling.  Much like your description: wrap a thin insulated wire around the switched hot lead that goes to the fan motor.  Or wrap a length of conductive foil around the conductor, with an insulated wire attached to the foil.  You have to ensure the foil or wire does not touch the metal enclosure.

Then just try it!  One lead of the LED to ground, the other lead of the LED to the capacitive sensor.  Be sure to connect a small signal diode in reverse polarity across the LED so that the reverse voltage does not destroy the LED.  Or use two LEDs connected in inverse parallel.

I would start off with about 2" (5cm) of foil wrapped around the hot conductor.  Aluminum foil would work well.

Please try it and report your results back here by modifying your question.